How to access the variable outside of scala match expression?
How to access the variables outside of the scala match expression? even if i declare as var, it does not return the updated value for test variable.
--updated the question
val x: Int = 2
var v1: String = ""
var v2: String = ""
x match {
    case 1 => 
       {var v1="testObj1"
        var v2="testobj2"
       }
}
println(v1,v2) -- should return testObj1 and testObj2


There now are 3 variables test. Remove the last two vars. Better something val test = x match ... => 10 ... => 11 ... ....

You can't return variables. You can, however, return values and assign them to new variables, or mutate existing mutable variables.

Check below code. Return value & assign to test variable.
val x: Int = 2
var test: Int = _

test = x match {
    case 1 =>  10
    case 2 =>  11
}

println(test)
test: Int = 11

var (v1, v2) = x match {
  case 1 => ("A", "B")
  case 2 => ("B", "C")
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

v1: String = B
v2: String = C

OR
var v1: String = ""
var v2: String = ""

x match {
    case 1 => {
       v1="testObj1"
       v2="testobj2"
    }
    case 2 => {
       v1="testObj3"
       v2="testobj4"
    }
}

scala> v1
res3: String = testObj3

scala> v2
res4: String = testobj4


what if i initializing two variables inside each case statement. How do i return both variable

Use tuple to return

can you update it with that example

Please update question with details

The problem is that you are creating new variables called v1 and v2 inside the case clauses so the old ones are not being updated.
It is better (more functional) to use assignment rather than var declarations:
val (v1, v2) = x match {
  case 1 => ("testObj1", "testobj2")
  case _ => ("default1", "default2")
}

